# PHP: Warning: imagejpeg failed to open stream

Tags: php, xml

I have the following script:

```
    <?php
  /* include database informations */
   include 'config.php';

  /* MySQLi Connection */
  $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

  /* MySQLi Check */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { printf('Connect Failed: %s\n', $mysqli->connect_error); exit(); }

  /* MySQLi Character */
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

  /* Cinestar VZ */
  $rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.blitz-cinestar.hr/rss.aspx?id=2128');

  /* Cinestar items */
  foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    /* Cinestar Poster Character */
    $item->orignaziv = str_replace('&rsquo;', '', mb_convert_encoding($item->orignaziv, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
    $item->orignaziv = str_replace(': ', ' -', mb_convert_encoding($item->orignaziv, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

    /* Cinestar Poster */
    if (!file_exists('./img/'.$item->orignaziv.' ('.$item->godina.').jpg')) {

      $remote_file = $item->plakat;
      $new_width = 117;
      $new_height = 168;
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
      $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
      imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
      imagejpeg($image_p, './img/'.ucfirst($item->orignaziv).' ('.$item->godina.').jpg', 100);
      imagedestroy($image_p);
    }

    /* MySQLi update|insert */
    $cinestar = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO cinestar (title, orignaziv, godina, redatelj, zanr, glumci, trajanje, rating, description, link, datumprikazivanja, trailer)
                                VALUES ('$item->title', '$item->orignaziv', '$item->godina', '$item->redatelj', '".ucfirst($item->zanr)."', '$item->glumci', '$item->trajanje', '$item->rating', '".strip_tags(substr($item->description, 0, strpos($item->description, '<a href')))."', '$item->link', '$item->datumprikazivanja', '".$item->trailer."')
                                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title='$item->title', godina='$item->godina', redatelj='$item->redatelj', zanr='".ucfirst($item->zanr)."', glumci='$item->glumci', trajanje='$item->trajanje', rating='$item->rating', description='".strip_tags(substr($item->description, 0, strpos($item->description, '<a href')))."', link='$item->link', datumprikazivanja='$item->datumprikazivanja', trailer='".$item->trailer."'");
  }

  /* MySQLi Close */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Please ignore MySQL stuff (it is whole script) and focus on PHP code that reads image from url resize it and save to img folder...i get this error when running script:

```
( ! ) Warning: imagejpeg(./img/Loving Vincent   (2017).jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\portal_ONLINE\UwAmp\www\filmovi_novi\inc\cinestar-rss.php on line 35
```

xml is on url:

```
http://www.blitz-cinestar.hr/rss.aspx?id=2128
```

I could not get point why it is not working...i try manually to copy vincent (2017).jpg to img folder but i get always this error...so some help or hint will be welcome..thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error, it looks like you are trying to construct the file name with spaces and special characters which are not  properly escaped.

This causes the `imagejpeg` to fail openning the stream as the file name which is provided is it invalid format.

Hence the **Invalid argument** Warning.

Try escaping the spaces and braces for it to work properly.

**Example of how the constructed file name should look**

```
Loving\ Vincent\ \ \ \(2017\).jpg
```

OR, you can strip out spaces and braces instead.

Comment: I try: imagejpeg($image_p, mysql_escape_string('./img/'.ucfirst($item->orignaziv).' ('.$item->godina.').jpg'), 100); but i get error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Could you please copy above code and remove mysql and try to run script on your server? i im pretty sure that will get same error...

Comment: try removing the spaces and braces from the file name which you are constructing.

Comment: i removed now...as you suggested...imagejpeg($image_p, './img/'.ucfirst($item->orignaziv).'('.$item->godina.').jpg', 100); but is the same error...

Comment: try this `imagejpeg($image_p, mysql_escape_string('./img/'.str_replace(" ", "\ ",ucfirst($item->orignaziv)).'\ \('.$item->godina.'\).jpg'), 100);`

Comment: I resolve it i found the error...in my mysql Loving Vincent was written like this: Loving Vincent: Van Goghov misterij and jpg to check and resize from url was Loving Vincent so i rename in mysql to be the same as image and now it works original code above..thanks for helping me out

Comment: Glad that I could be of help. Thank you!